# How to provide licence for a Qt App?

Tags: qt, licensing

I saw in Qt's download page (http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) that Qt is available under GPL v3, LGPL v2 and a commercial license. I installed Qt with the Windows offline installer, downloaded from that download page.
I finished my app and i want to make everything perfectly in the licence area.
My app is closed source, free and links dinamicly, so LGPL v2 is ok for it. But where, and how do I inform the users about the licencing? Do I have to write it in a txt or into the program? Do I have to provide a licence for every qt .dll files? Ow how do I required to do it?
Anyway, where do i know that im using the LGPL version of Qt and not the GPL v3? Or the two are the same (from the installed QT SDK view), and I can decide which licenc do I want to use when I publish my work?
So if I change my mind and I want to put my app under a GPL v3 licence, the only thing I have to do is provide a different licence?

(Note: I know there are differeces between the requirments of GPL v3 and LGPL, but now I'm interested in the procedure of licence deploying.)

(Sorry for bad english)

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: @JasonMArcher I'm OK with migrating it to the Programmes.SE site, if somebody can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Qt Licensing, you don't need to tell what version of Qt you uses. Optionally, you can put an "About Qt" functionnality that displays a popup about the framework (with `qApp->aboutQt();`) if you want.

If you want to put your app under (L)GPL, you have to do this :

1. You have to free your code (of course)
2. Give a copy of the LGPL with your program (in a file called "COPYING.LESSER" for LGPL or "COPYING" for GPL, for example).
3. At the beginning of every source file, you have to write something like this (here for LGPLv3 license) :

> *MySoft* is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
>
> *MySoft* is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
>
> You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License along with *MySoft*. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
>   
>   For more informations, you can visit the GNU website here : http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html